# A Spring Boot application does REST -> Service -> Dataset (Spark) with Java. I would some of the datasets to be written in Scala. Is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scala, apache-spark

I wrote an application with *Spring Boot* in *Java*.

Inside are REST calls, Spring boot business services (`@Service`), and some of these services are using *Apache Spark* to create *Datasets* doing some calculations and returning lists of *Java* POJO objects.

For example, a *Spring Boot* service

```java
@Service
public class AssociationsService
```

has a method that returns a list of associations:

```java
/**
 * Obtenir la liste des associations d'une commune.
 * @param session Session Spark.
 * @param anneeRNA Année du Registre National des Associations
 * @param anneeCOG Année du Code Officiel Géographique.
 * @param codeCommune Code Commune.
 * @return Liste des associations.
 */
public List<Association> obtenirAssociations(SparkSession session, int anneeRNA, int anneeCOG, CodeCommune codeCommune) {
   Objects.requireNonNull(codeCommune, "Le code commune où rechercher des associations ne peut pas valoir null.");
   
   LOGGER.info("Obtention des associations présentes en {} pour la commune de code {} du COG {}", anneeRNA, codeCommune, anneeCOG);
   
   Dataset<Row> rowAssociations = this.associationsDataset.rowAssociations(session, anneeRNA, anneeCOG, true, TriAssociations.CODE_COMMUNE)
      .where(col("codeDepartement").equalTo(codeCommune.getNumeroDepartement())
            .and(col("codeCommune").equalTo(codeCommune.getDepartementEtCommune())));
   
   return this.associationsDataset.toAssociations(rowAssociations);
}
```

where `Association` is a business object (*Java* POJO) whose members are `String`, `Integer`... or others POJOs.

```java
public class Association extends ObjetMetierSpark {
   /** Serial ID.*/
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -7206954677114644630L;

   /** Numéro Waldec national unique de l’association. */
   private NumeroWaldec numeroWaldec;
   
   /** Ancien numéro waldec. */
   private AncienNumeroWaldec ancienNumeroWaldec;
   
   /** Siret de l'association (facultatif). */
   private SIRET siret;
   
   /** Numéro d'association reconnue d'utilité publique (RUP) attribué par le Ministère. */
   private NumeroRUP numeroRUP;

   /** Code du site gestionnaire de l’association */
   private String gestion;

   /** Nature de l'association : simplement déclarée 1901 ou autre */
   private String nature;

   /** Regroupement de l'association : simple ou union ou fédération (S, U, F). */
   private RegroupementAssociation groupement;

   /** Nom long de l'association. */
   private String titre;

   // Getters and setters following
   [...]
```

and the service method uses *Spark* with a dataset implemented in a class named `AssociationWaldecDataset` to do its job:

```java
/**
 * Obtenir un Dataset Row du registre national des associations actives.
 * @param session Session Spark.
 * @param anneeRNA Année du registre.
 * @param anneeCOG Année du Code Officiel Géographique.
 * @param actives true si seules les associations actives doivent être retenues.
 * @param tri Tri à sélectionner.
 * @param verifications Vérifications optionnelles à mener.
 * @return Dataset des associations.
 * @throws TechniqueException si un incident survient.
 */
public Dataset<Row> rowAssociations(SparkSession session, int anneeRNA, int anneeCOG, boolean actives, TriAssociations tri, @SuppressWarnings("unused") Verification... verifications) throws TechniqueException {
   Parqueteur<TriAssociations> parqueteur = new Parqueteur<>(this.tempDir, isCacheUtilise(), "associationsRNA", "{0,number,#0}_{1,number,#0}_{2}", TriAssociations.values());
   Dataset<Row> associations = parqueteur.loadFromStore(session, tri, anneeRNA, anneeCOG, actives);
   
   if (associations != null) {
      return associations;
   }
   
   associations = loadAndRenameAssociationsCSV(session, anneeRNA, anneeCOG, tri);

   // Ejecter les associations qui n'ont ni nom, ni objet social.
   int indexTitre = associations.schema().fieldIndex("titre");
   int indexObjet = associations.schema().fieldIndex("objet");

   LongAccumulator sansObjetSocial = session.sparkContext().longAccumulator("sans_objet_social");
   LongAccumulator rnaInvalide = session.sparkContext().longAccumulator("rna_invalide");
   
   associations = associations.filter((FilterFunction<Row>)f -> {
      if (f.isNullAt(indexTitre) && f.isNullAt(indexObjet)) {
         LOGGER.warn("Une association RNA {} dans la commune de {} ({}) n'a ni titre ni objet et n'est pas retenue.", 
            f.getAs("numero_waldec"), f.getAs("adresse_siege_nom_commune"), f.getAs("adresse_siege_code_commune"));
         
         sansObjetSocial.add(1);
         return false;
      }
      
      if (f.getAs("numero_waldec").toString().length() != 10) {
         LOGGER.warn("Une association RNA {} dans la commune de {} ({}) n'a pas d'identifiant waldec et est écartée.", 
            f.getAs("numero_waldec"), f.getAs("adresse_siege_nom_commune"), f.getAs("adresse_siege_code_commune"));
         
         rnaInvalide.add(1);
      }
      
      // Il peut être demandé que seules les associations actives soient retenues.
      if (actives) {
         if ("A".equals(f.getAs("position_activite")) == false) {
            return false;
         }
      }
      
      return true;
   });

   // Joindre les objets sociaux, en outer.
   Dataset<Row> objetsSociaux = this.objetsSociauxDataset.rowObjetsSociaux(session, anneeRNA);
   
   associations = associations.join(objetsSociaux, associations.col("code_objet_social1").equalTo(objetsSociaux.col("code_objet_social")), "outer")
      .withColumnRenamed("libelle_objet_social", "libelle_objet_social1")
      .drop("code_objet_social");

   associations = associations.join(objetsSociaux, associations.col("code_objet_social2").equalTo(objetsSociaux.col("code_objet_social")), "outer")
      .withColumnRenamed("libelle_objet_social", "libelle_objet_social2")
      .drop("code_objet_social");
   
   // Remplacer les noms de communes par celles officielles.
   Dataset<Row> communes = this.cogDataset.rowCommunes(session, anneeCOG).select("codeCommune", "nomCommune", "codeRegion", "codeDepartement", "codeEPCI", "nomEPCI", "populationTotale");
   
   associations = associations.join(communes, associations.col("adresse_siege_code_commune").equalTo(communes.col("codeCommune")), "inner")
      .drop("adresse_siege_code_commune", "adresse_siege_nom_commune");
   associations = parqueteur.appliquer(tri, associations);

   // Supprimer les caractères parasites majeurs des noms d'associations, objets sociaux, adresses.
   associations = correctionDonneesInvalides(associations, true);
   associations = associations.persist(); // Important : optimise beaucoup.
   
   // Calculer l'ancienneté d'existence des associations qui ont une date de création.
   Column nombreAnneesExistence = when(col("date_creation").equalTo(null), null).
      otherwise(datediff(current_date(), col("date_creation")).$div(lit(365)));
   
   associations = associations.withColumn("nombreAnneesExistence", nombreAnneesExistence);

   // Calculer l'ancienneté de la dernière déclaration quand la date est connue.
   Column nombreAnneesDerniereDeclaration = when(col("date_derniere_declaration").equalTo(null), null).
      otherwise(datediff(current_date(), col("date_derniere_declaration")).$div(lit(365)));
   
   associations = associations.withColumn("nombreAnneesDerniereDeclaration", nombreAnneesDerniereDeclaration);

   if (parqueteur.saveToStore(tri, associations, anneeRNA, anneeCOG, actives)) {
      LOGGER.info("Le dataset des associations inscrites au registre national de {} et année COG {}, tri par {} est constitué et stocké.", anneeRNA, anneeCOG, tri);
   }
   
   if (associations.isEmpty() == false) {
      LOGGER.info("Anomalies rencontrées :");
      LOGGER.info("\t{} RNA étaient mal constitués : enregistrements invalides.", rnaInvalide.count());
      LOGGER.info("\t{} associations étaient sans titre ni objet.", sansObjetSocial.count());
   }

   return associations;
}
```

But the more datasets of this kind I'm writting and the more I think that it would be convenient if this Dataset code, this method `rowAssociations`, was written in *Scala* instead of *Java*, that is said to be more accurate, have more abilities to handle *Apache Spark*.

But you see where the *Spark* part of my application is... at the end of the flow of the calls that are all in *Java*.

Rest -> Spring-Boot Service -> Spark
Everyone using *Java* business objects. (Some other Spring Boot services, knowing nothing about *Spark*, could use the business objet `Association` for another need).

In *Maven* I have set the build plugin to allow the compilation of `src/main/scala` along with `src/main/java`:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    
                    <configuration>
                        <recompileMode>all</recompileMode>
                        <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    
                    <configuration>
                        <recompileMode>all</recompileMode>
                        <testSourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/scala</testSourceDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            
            <configuration>
                <scalaVersion>2.12.10</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**But I've left my `src/main/scala` empty yet !**

Because I'm troubled.
I don't know how my Spring boot `AssociationsService` method written in *Java* with its `Association` POJO
can call a *Scala* dataset class if I choose to create an `AssociationWaldecDataset.scala` file to replace the `AssociationWaldecDataset.java` one for the implementation of the `AssociationWaldecDataset` class.

Is it possible or am I definitively tied to continue writting my *Spark* part in *Java*?

Comment: *"in Scala instead of Java, that is said to be more accurate"* - What is "not accurate" in the code that you showed here?

Comment: @mentallurg I don't really know, but I've been told many times that if I use _Scala_ instead, I will create more efficient code, more concise, and maybe there could be methods unavailable in _Java_ that I could use with _Scala_? I'm following advices that are telling me that I would do better if I change the language for the Big Data part of the application.

Comment: Not sure to understand: your Spark application runs within the REST endpoint?

Comment: @GaëlJ Yes. A REST method `public List<Association> obtenirAssociations(int anneeRNA, int anneeCOG, String codeCommune)` is available, mostly to be called by an _Angular_ web page. That REST method calls the `AssociationsService` (_Spring Boot_) that calls the `AssociationWaldecDataset` (_Spark_). Most of the time, _Spark_ only has to do a lookup in _Parquet_ files it had generated before. If data isn't available yet, it has to built it from open data CSV files.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan: If you don't really know, then there is no sense to do it. Java, Scala, C#, Node.JS etc. are just tools to solve some business problem. Also if you want to replace one tool with another, there should be a benefit for the business. If **you** see no benefit, then there is no reason to change anything, no matter who what says. I would suggest you: Work with technology you have, get deeper understanding, get more experience. Only after **you** see *some* disadvantages in *some* cases, it makes sense to consider any other tools.

Comment: @mentallurg I agree with you, and I won't force me. It seems to me that _Scala_ _could_ improve writing the Big Data code of my application, and I will have to check the reality of this. But I'm just asking the question in this post: is it possible or not to do a call from _Java_ to _Scala_ (using mainly _Java_ objects for arguments, and _Java_ classes for models of result, but the target of the call is a _Scala_ method on a _Scala_ object)? If I had asked the opposite (call _Java_ from _Scala_) everyone would have told me: "_It's easy and immediate!_", but in this direction _Java_ to _Scala_?

Comment: @MarcLeBihan: Sure, you can call Scala from Java, because Scala is running in JVM.

Comment: @mentallurg That's already a good news. Thanks. But how? Does methods asking for `scala.collection` objects, for example, accept directly classical `java.utils` collection for parameters?

Comment: @MarcLeBihan: 1) SO is questions / answers site, not a tutorial point. Tell us what you have done so far, what is clear, what remains unclear, what works, what doesn't work, and what exactly is your question or problem. 2) Asking too broad questions is not allowed on SO, such questions will be closed. Try to formulate your question in such way, that it is focused on small topic.